# Regex Javascript use variable within pattern

Tags: javascript, regex

I know that this's been asked before but none of the suggested solutions worked for me. I've got the following:

```
  var regex = new RegExp(/D0030001 IN/gi);
  $("p").filter(function () {
        return regex.test(this.id); 
   }).css("background-color","blue");
```

This one works fine. However, when I try to do

```
 spl = [];
 spl[0] = "D0030001";
 spl[1] = "IN";
 var regex = new RegExp("/" + spl[0] + " " + spl[1] + "/gi");
       $("p").filter(function () {
        return regex.test(this.id); 
   }).css("background-color","blue");
```

This one doesn't work. In other words I need to use variables to construct the regex pattern. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use the second argument of RegExp constructor to set the flags and you don't need `/ /` delimiters.

```
var regex = new RegExp(spl[0] + " " + spl[1], "gi");
```